# npm install lite-server --save-dev installation error

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm, npm-install

I am trying to use node for the first time,installed node.js below is the information

```
node -v
v14.4.0
npm -v
6.14.5
```

Completed the setup by creating a package.json file, then tried to install lite-server using the command 
npm install lite-server --save-dev produced the folllowing error:

```
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ojhaa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-06T06_54_54_480Z-debug.log
```

Followed by 
npm cache clean --force

Here is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "git-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "\"This is a test directory to learn git and node\"",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run lite",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lite": "lite-server"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/apoorva0212/git-test.git"
  },
  "author": "\"Apoorva Ojha\"",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/apoorva0212/git-test/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/apoorva0212/git-test#readme"
}
```

But still I get the same error. Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you, in advance.

Comment: delete `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and try again.

Comment: @AluanHaddad There is no such folder as node_modules.

Comment: Is there a `package.json`? If not run `npm init`

Comment: Yes, there is a `package.json`.

Comment: Add your `package.json` to the question

Comment: Added. Please, check it.

Comment: Using that `package.json` running `npm install --save-dev lite-server` works perfectly. I have the exact same versions of Node and npm. Try to reinstall nodejs and make sure you check the box for installing optional dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing the dependency on [`lite-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server)

try to install lite-server dependency

```sh
npm install lite-server --save-dev
```

then invoke `npm run lite`